# Altium footprint Wizard SOT669

Tags: mosfet, altium, footprint

Anyone know if the footprint wizard in Altium can be used to generate SOT669 package footprints?

It appears to me that its only capable of 3 lead MOSFETs. I searched the web and couldn't find anything, I don't mind making footprints by hand but its a standard form factor and I'm a little confused why its not an included option.

Someone feel free to correct me if I am missing something entirely within the options on Altium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altium seems entirely happy to generate DPAK-style footprints with arbitrary numbers of leads and arbitrary pitch:

[image]

[image]

You may have to override most of the default dimensions, but that should still be easier then doing it manually.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there was a way to do it, and come to think of it I used that part of the tool in the past I had just forgotten. Thanks again!